# How to configure webpack in live server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I am new at `webpack`. I was able to configure this module for localhost. Now I need to host it. So, I have changed `IP` address `webpack.config.js` file but it does not work. The `webpack.config.js` is as below:

```
var config = {
entry: './main.js',

output: {
    path:'./',
    filename: 'index.js',
},

devServer: {
    inline: true,
    host: '127.0.0.1', // in this section, I have tried to change IP address by server IP
    port: 3000
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
}
}

module.exports = config;
```

In the host section, I am trying the change the IP address by the server's IP. When I run the command `npm start`, it shows a lot of errors. Could you tell me someone what is the correct way to use webapck at the live server?

Comment: Do not use webpack in production ,since its name guides you that it create package of what you implement in development environment .. it is recommended to generate a bundle from webpack , then , host your code in webserver like nginx.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line :

```
host: '127.0.0.1', // in this section, I have tried to change IP
```

By :

```
host: '0.0.0.0', // in this section, I have tried to change IP
```